# Is it possible to prevent Max from switching weapons during cutscenes?

Tags: max-payne-3

Each time a cutscene starts (and god knows it's pretty much *all the time* in this game), Max switches back to any single right handed weapon he's got.  This is highly annoying, mostly when the cutscene leads to a gunfight: guns are starting blazing everywhere in a second and you have a simple handgun 9mm instead of your favorite ak47, looted at the price of your life a few minutes before.
By the time you understand it, you are dead already.

Comment: You shouldn't accept an answer if it doesn't provide a solution for your question. [The current answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/94654/148510) is good, but as the author states, he misunderstood.

Comment: The answer is that there's no solution, so it's acceptable.

Comment: There may be, especially if PC-only answers (mods) are accepted.

Comment: Man.  Q: "is it possible to [...] ?"  A: "no".  It's perfectly ok to accept that answer.  If you've got a better one, just post it and quit fiddling around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm aware of no mechanism to prevent this replacement.

From the visual developer's standpoint, having to create a cutscene that's believable from both a single-handed and two-handed weapon stance is rather limiting. There's a long history of video games simply defaulting to a particular weapon in cutscenes (usually that character's 'signature weapon', if any) to remove that restriction.

For example, suppose the cutscene involves the character chancing upon two enemies, unseen, then dipping into cover. The means of taking cover while maintaining combat readiness is very different when wielding a pistol than it is when wielding an assault rifle (and both are different from wielding a heavy weapon, such as an RPG). Rather than generating different cutscenes for each possibility (a waste of time and space), or solving this procedurally, most developers simply default to a particular weapon.

Comment: Yep I understand that, and have no problem with the way they deal with this recurring video game "issue".  But my question is rather: once the cutscene is over, why don't they let the player continue playing with the weapon he was wielding *before* the cutscene's beginning (when it's possible; e.g. when Max didn't had to throw it away for some fancy acrobatics)?

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the question. Answer still applies though; I'm aware of no mechanism to get around that.